# Json variable from MVC Controller always returning "undefined"

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a dot net core MVC application. My controller has the following function:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Delete(string chkId)
        {
            if (chkId == "" || chkId == null)
                StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);

            List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                stringList = chkId.ToString().Split(',').ToList();
                for (var i = 0; i < stringList.Count(); i++)
                {
                    StringDA.Delete(Convert.ToInt64(stringList[i]), GetString());
                }
                string result = "Success";
                return Json(result, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Now my View is trying to access the function using following jquery.

```
$('#btnDelete').on('click', function () {
    // Code.........
            var msg = "Are you sure you want to delete?";
            var check = confirm(msg);
            //alert(chkVal);
            if (check == true) {
                var join_selected_values = chkVal.join(",");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/General/Delete",
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: 'chkId=' + join_selected_values,
                    success: function (response) {
                        //alert(response.result);
                        if (response.result == "Success") {
                            alert("Record(s) deleted");
                            ..........
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Error in Appication");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

But when I am testing my application **response.resrult** always throws "undefined" even controller function is okey. I can not understand why response.resrult is undefined when I am explicitly declaring it as "Success"?

Comment: `resrult` is misspelled the correct word is `result` without a second **r**. Even if you consistently use it, you never actually set a response field as `resrult`. Check what the `response` actually contains.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for mentioning it. In my actual project variable declaration was okay. So it is giving the same result i.e. "undefined".

Comment: And did you check what you actually get from the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should define result variable

```
return new JsonResult( new { result="Sucess" } );
```